# LSTM always predicts the same class

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I’m trying to solve an nlp classification problem with a LSTM. The code for the model is defined here:

```
class LSTM(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self, hidden_size, embedding_size=66 ):

      super().__init__()
      self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embedding_size, hidden_size, batch_first = True, bidirectional = True)
      self.fc = nn.Linear(2*hidden_size,2)

  def forward(self, input_seq):
      
      output, (hidden_state, cell_state) = self.lstm(input_seq)

      hidden_state = torch.cat((hidden_state[-1,:], hidden_state[-2,:]), -1)

      logits = self.fc(hidden_state)
      
      return nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)(logits)
```

And the function I’m using to train this model is here:

```
def train_loop(dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    
    loss_fn = loss_fn
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    model.train()
    zeros = 0
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):

        # Transform string into tensor
        tensor = torch.zeros(1,len(X[0]),66)
        for i in range(len(X[0])):
            tensor[0][i][ctoi[X[0][i]]] = 1

        pred = model(tensor)

        target = torch.zeros(2, dtype=torch.long)
        target[y] = 1
        
        if batch % 100 == 0:
            print(pred.squeeze(), target)
        loss = loss_fn(pred.squeeze(), target)

        # Backpropagation
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if pred.squeeze().argmax() == 0:
            zeros += 1

        if batch % 100 == 0:
            loss, current = loss.item(), batch * len(X)
            print(f"loss: {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}]")

    print(f'In trainning predicted {zeros} zeroes out of {size} samples')
```

The X’s are still strings, that’s why I need to convert them to tensors before running it through the model. The y’s are either a 0 or 1 (since its a binary classification problem), that I need to convert to a tensor of shape (2,) to run through the loss function.

For some reason I keep getting the same class predicted for every input. The classes are not even that unbalanced (~45% to 55%), and I’ve tried changing the weights of the classes in the loss function with no improvements, it either converges to predicting always a 0 or always a 1. Most of the time it it converges to predicting always a 0, which makes even less sense because what happens usually is that the class 0 has less samples than class 1.

Comment: A lot of this logic is somewhat weird. Why not handle one-hot encoding your strings in your dataset? Your `y` should be `{0,1}` and not a vector of length 2.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're training a binary classification model, your output dim should be 1 (corresponding to a single probability P(y|x)). This means that the `y` you're retrieving from your dataloader should be the y used in your loss function (assuming a cross-entropy loss). The predicted class is therefore `y_hat = round(pred)` (i.e., is the prediction >= 0.5).

As a point of clarity, it would be much easier to follow your logic if the one-hot encoding happened within your dataset (either in `__getitem__` or `__iter__`). It's also worth noting that you don't use embeddings, so the code of your classifier is a bit misleading.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you, I should have made it clearer, but I just started learning Pytorch yesterday and have been doing a lot of debugging so I just sent the code how it is now, my bad!